# Avoiding rounding errors for unit cost/profit per product (from bulk purchase)

Tags: database-design

For an application I'm working on, I'm required to calculate the cost per product (we buy in bulk) as well as calculate the profit when a unit is sold.

The naive approach would be to store the cost directly as rounded result.

For example, if I buy 3 products for $1 and sell them for $1 each (storing integer here, so numbers are in cents)

```
100 / 3 = 33 => cost per unit

Database Columns: cost=33, price=100
```

Now if I sell all 3 of them

```
3 * price = 300
total cost = 33 * 3 = 99
total profit = 300 - 99 = 201
```

which is wrong. You can store higher precisions, but if your product price is high, then you will still have the same error.

The other approach which I can think of, is to store the bulk purchase price and volume, so your profit calculation is always accurate

```
Database columns: bulkprice=100, amount=3, price=100

3 * price = 300
total cost = (100/3) * 3 = 100
total profit = 300 - 100 = 100 -> correct!
```

However this approach would introduce extra complexity into calculations as well as our database queries.

So my question is:

- What's the industry's normal approach to this problem?
- Are there any other downsides to the fraction approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right data type. *Integer* (for storing cents) isn't the right data type. And 100/3 doesn't equal 33. There's no sane reason to use division when you're recording costs or sales.

Use `numeric` or `decimal` data types. I'll use a single table for this, because it appears that's what you're doing.(Or thinking of doing.)

```
create table test (
  test_id integer primary key,
  trans_type char(1) not null 
    check(trans_type in ('b', 's')),
  cost numeric (14, 2) not null
    check (cost >= 0),
  qty integer not null 
    check (qty > 0)
);

-- Buy three things for a dollar.
insert into test values (1, 'b', 1.00, 3);

-- Sell each thing for a dollar.
insert into test values
(2, 's', 1.00, 1),
(3, 's', 1.00, 1),
(4, 's', 1.00, 1);

-- total cost
select sum(cost) as total_cost from test where trans_type = 'b';
```

```
total_cost
1.00
```

```
-- Sales and costs
select (select sum(cost) 
        from test 
        where trans_type = 's') as sales,
       (select sum(cost)
        from test
        where trans_type = 'b') as costs;
```

```
sales  costs
3.00   1.00
```

```
-- Total profit
select sales - costs as profit 
from (select (select sum(cost) 
              from test 
              where trans_type = 's') as sales,
              (select sum(cost)
              from test
              where trans_type = 'b') as costs) x;
```

```
profit
2.00
```

*Unit cost* is something you might find on a report, but not something you'd usually find stored in an accounting system. You can round or not. (I did not.)

```
-- Unit cost
select test_id, cost/qty as unit_cost 
from test 
where trans_type = 'b';
```

```
test_id  unit_cost
1        0.33333333333333333333
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `int`s should be preferred for dealing with currency. For example http://www.setfiremedia.com/blog/7-top-tips-for-coding-with-currency. What is your rationale for using `numeric` or `decimal`?

Comment: Integers take extra work to maintain scaling. To fix that, most (all?) SQL dbms offer a "money" or "currency" data type that's a scaled bigint. But scaling varies from vendor to vendor, limiting portability.  `numeric(p,n)` is portable to every SQL dbms, AFAIK. Also, vendors that offer "money" data types often recommend `numeric` instead. [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) "The type numeric can store numbers with a very large number of digits and perform calculations exactly. It is especially recommended for storing monetary amounts..."

Comment: numeric(19,4) is a common size for money amounts, at least in Java. Helps with bankers' rounding.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: numeric(19, 4) covers SQL Server's "currency" data type exactly. SQL Server's "currency" data type is a scaled bigint. PostgreSQL's monetary data type also uses a scaled bigint, but they define it as numeric(19, 2).